# cvlc hanging my pi

Tags: video, streaming

I am using the following commands to stream live HD video from my new Raspberry Pi B+ 512MB.
It works great for about 5 to 10 minutes, then everything hangs and I have to remove power and re-boot the pi.  I am using the standard 5 MPixel camera module.

Two questions:

1. Is there a better way to do this?  Most of the suggestions I have seen use MJPEG or older technologies where this seemed to be HD video.
2. Can anyone recommend any troubleshooting tips?  I have looked at /var/log/messages, syslog, etc. but I don't find any clues as to why it is hanging up.

I tried running top while it was running to see if I was overwhelming my system, but it never seemed to pass 50% utilization before hanging.

**Commands are:**

```
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0 --v4l2-width 1920 --v4l2-height 1080 --v4l2-chroma h264 --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=0.0.0.0:12345}'
```

Comment: How are you powering the pi? Are you using Ethernet or WiFi? Is it possible you are under or overflowing a buffer?

Comment: Powering with a standard wall-wart with mini-usb connector that came as part of the kit.  The commands above are all that I am running.  I don't know if they might overflow or underflow a buffer.  Is there another way to stream the HD video?

Answer (score 2):

Any thing that hangs/kills the Pi outright sounds like power issues.

Power issues on the Pi are often not consistent e.g. the Pi will operate without issue for minutes, hours, days, etc. Before failing.

Please unplug everything and [check the power test points](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Troubleshooting_power_problems).

Its also worth noting that USB power plugs often fail to supply the require 5v EVEN if they are labelled to do such. If the PSU is providing the correct voltage the cable maybe losing enough to cause the Pi problems(I have had direct experience of this, do not buy cheap USB cables).

My [own experiments](http://www.jumpstation.co.uk/flog/Jun2013.html#210620131752) showed that a difference of just 0.15v(avg) was enough to cause sporadic stability issues, that would affect the image on the SD card.

Add amp information and test

Known supported SD cards
  http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  I haven't tried all of your suggestions yet, but what I have done is swap out the Raspberry Pi.  I had an old Model B (512) that I connected and it runs the camera just fine using the same power source.  I will follow your suggestions to trouble shoot the one that fails.  Thanks!